# Can a Prop show that all entries of a list equal Type@{U} for any U?

Tags: coq

In Coq, is it possible to write a predicate (`list Type -> Prop`) that is only provable if all entries of the list are of the form `Type@{U}`?

The predicate should accept Types from different universes within the same list. For example, `[Type@{U1}; Type@{U2}]` should be accepted, where `U1 < U2`. Other types, such as `nat`, should not be accepted in the list.

The closest I was able to get is to have the predicate verify that each entry of the list is a universe-like type that has some of the properties of `Type@{U}`:

- The universe-like types form a chain, where the previous one is embedded within the next.
- `Set` is at the start of the chain.
- Each universe-like type has an export function that can convert an inhabitant of the universe-like type, `T: UT`, into an inhabitant of `T@{max}`. That is, `export: UT -> Type@{max}`.

However, that predicate also accepts types which are not of the form `Type%{U}`, such as `(Type * nat)%type`.

```
Require Import List.

Import ListNotations.

Inductive TypeChain: forall (carrier: Type), (carrier -> Type) -> Type :=
| TypeChainSet: TypeChain Set (fun s: Set => s)
| TypeChainNext:
  forall prev_carrier prev_export,
  TypeChain prev_carrier prev_export ->
  forall carrier (export: carrier -> Type) (import: prev_carrier -> carrier),
  (forall p: prev_carrier, export (import p) = prev_export p) ->
  forall prev_embed,
  (export (prev_embed) = prev_carrier) ->
  TypeChain carrier export.

Inductive InTypeChain (T: Type):
    forall {carrier export}, TypeChain carrier export -> Prop :=
| InTypeChainTop: forall export (chain: TypeChain T export),
  InTypeChain T chain
| InTypeChainPrev:
  forall prev_carrier prev_export prev_chain,
  InTypeChain T prev_chain ->
  forall carrier export import export_imported prev_embed prev_embed_matches,
  InTypeChain T (TypeChainNext prev_carrier prev_export prev_chain carrier
                 export import export_imported prev_embed prev_embed_matches).

Definition ListContainsOnlyTypes (l: list Type) :=
exists carrier export (c: TypeChain carrier export),
  Forall (fun T => InTypeChain T c) l.
```

```
Module GoodExample.

Universe U1 U2.
Constraint U1 < U2.

Definition ChainU2: TypeChain Type@{U2} (fun T => T).
Proof.
  unshelve eapply (TypeChainNext Type@{U1}); auto.
  unshelve eapply (TypeChainNext Type@{Set}); auto.
  unshelve apply TypeChainSet.
Defined.

Example GoodListAccepted: ListContainsOnlyTypes [Type@{U1}; Set; Type@{U2}].
Proof.
  eexists.
  eexists.
  exists ChainU2.
  eauto 7 using InTypeChain.
Qed.

End GoodExample.
```

```
Module BadExample.

Definition BadChain: TypeChain (Type * nat) (fun T => fst T).
Proof.
  unshelve eapply (TypeChainNext Set); auto.
  - exact (fun s:Set => (s:Type, 0)).
  - exact (Set, 0).
  - apply TypeChainSet.
  - reflexivity.
  - reflexivity.
Defined.

Example BadListAccepted: ListContainsOnlyTypes [(Type * nat)%type; Set].
Proof.
  eexists.
  eexists.
  exists BadChain.
  eauto using InTypeChain.
Qed.

End BadExample.
```

Comment: Can you prove that `nat` is not equal to `nat * nat` in Coq?

Comment: I'm not an expert on these things, but I think you can only prove that two types are not equal in Coq if their cardinality is different. `nat` and `nat * nat` are both countably infinite types. So without adding axioms, you can't prove that they are equal or not equal.

Comment: Since you can't disprove that, if you add `nat = (nat*nat)` as an axiom there will be no inconsistency. Similarly adding the axiom about universes `Type = Type*nat` does not result in inconsistencies.

Comment: Now if you add that axiom, you can now rewrite using that. So you can never distinguish these two things with any definition whatsoever. Due to its consistency, even without that axiom you can't disprove the possibility.

Comment: There's a difference between what can't be proved and what is false. For example, without adding axioms, one can't prove or disprove that `(Set -> bool) = Set`. However, without axioms, `ListContainsOnlyTypes` blocks using that as a carrier.

Is it possible to improve my example `ListContainsOnlyTypes` to reject more carriers that are not `Type%{U}`?

Comment: I have proved that it is impossible to reject `Type * nat`. And the proof uses the relationship between "what can't be proved and what is false", as you say.

Comment: @KyleStemen: here's [a proof that `(Set -> bool) = Set -> False`](https://gist.github.com/andrejbauer/4623bba71854332cc9f396cdd22524fb), so your claim above is incorrect.

Comment: @AndrejBauer, that's an interesting proof. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Trebor, I'd be interested in seeing the proof.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, universes are very underspecified in CIC, so that the kind of things you want to do is not easily feasible.

If you want to do "intensional" analysis of types, a good solution is often to consider *codes* rather than types. Here is a very naïve example:

```
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Inductive code : Type :=
  | ty : code
  | ar : code -> code -> code
  | n : code.

Fixpoint El (c : code) : Type :=
  match c with
  | ty => Type
  | ar c1 c2 => El c1 -> El c2
  | n => nat
  end.

Inductive CodeChain : list code -> Prop :=
  | cnil : CodeChain []
  | ccons l : CodeChain l -> CodeChain (ty :: l).

Definition TypeChain (l : list Type) : Prop :=
  exists l', l = map El l' /\ CodeChain l'.
```

There are multiple difficulties here, however.

First, while `CodeChain` encodes the predicate you are looking for, `TypeChain` is somewhat too lose again, because eg we cannot derive falsity from `TypeChain [nat*Type]`, while we can derive it from eg `CodeChain [n]`.
Basically, applying `El` loses the intensional content you are looking for. So you should as much as possible reason on the codes rather than the types.

Second, because Coq cannot reason about universe levels is a first class way, you cannot specify in your codes that the `ty` constructor should be at a given level.

Third, and maybe the biggest limitation, this inductive presentation of codes does not scale to dependent types. Indeed, in such a setting you would want to write a constructor for dependent function type as `ar : forall A : code, (El A -> code) -> code`, but this means `El` and `code` need to be defined mutually. This is called an inductive-recursive definition, and is not available in Coq (but it is in Agda for instance).

Comment: Does this solve the dependent types problem with codes in Coq?

Inductive codeable : Type -> Type :=
  | ty : codeable Type
  | ar : forall input, codeable input -> forall (output: input -> Type), (forall i, codeable (output i)) -> codeable (forall i, output i)
  | n : codeable nat.

Record code := {
  El: Type;
  witness: codeable El;
}.

Comment: Your `TypeChain` predicate basically says that all of the types in the list can be expressed as codes instead. It allows types like `nat -> nat`, because they can be expressed as codes. However in my example, `ListContainsOnlyTypes` rejects `nat -> nat`, because it is too different from `Type`.

I think the point you are trying to make is that I should avoid using `Type` in the rest of my program and use codes instead. In this case, the second difficulty you listed (cannot reason about universe levels) is a bigger deal. That limits the kinds of higher order functions that are accepted.

Comment: As to your first comment: indeed, yes, this is a way to go around the issue, by replacing induction-recursion with indices. Basically, you replace the `El` function by a predicate describing its graph. You lose computation, but you gain the ability to define it in Coq.

Comment: As for the second comment, this is not the case: the `CodeChain` predicate says that all elements in the list are `ty`, the code for `Type`. So applying `map El` to such a list must result in a list where all elements are `Type`. The issue being that `l = map El l'` hits the issue of equality between types again.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "limiting the kinds of higher order functions that are accepted", though?

Comment: I don't know the right terminology to explain it. With the codes you gave, you can't prove this:
```
Require Import EqdepFacts.

Inductive awkward_option : Type -> Type :=
| awkward_none: forall T, awkward_option T
| awkward_some: forall T, T -> awkward_option T.

Theorem holds_awkward_option: exists code v, eq_dep _ (fun T => T) _ awkward_option (El code) v.
```

Comment: The difficulty with your `awkward_option` is that it is a "large" inductive type, and so it is messing up with universe levels. But with a bit of control on universe levels, changing your inductive to:
```
Inductive awkward_option@{u v} : Type@{u} -> Type@{u} :=
  | awkward_none: forall (T : Type@{v}), awkward_option T
  | awkward_some: forall (T : Type@{v}), T -> awkward_option T.
```
your goal becomes provable by `now eexists (ar ty ty), awkward_option`.

Comment: The way you specified universes for awkward_option changes its meaning. The following theorem is only true with the universes you specified: Require Import Coq.Logic.Hurkens.
Theorem awkward_option_not_always_inhabited: exists T, awkward_option T -> False.
Proof.
  exists (Type@{awkward_option.v}).
  inversion 1; eauto using TypeNeqSmallType.paradox.
Qed.

Comment: Right, you need `u` to be large for `awkward_option Type@{u}` to be inhabited… I guess Coq is not very suitable to get a precise control over universe levels and have fancy codes. Depending on your setting you might consider moving over to Agda, where this kind of things is easier.